# SQL Server 2005 Database Mail Failures

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, sqlmail

I am running database mail on a SQL 2005 box. Occasionally mails fail to send, by quering the msdb.dbo.sysmail_mailitems table i can see there are items with a sent_status of "2", which is failed.  I can query the **sysmail_faileditems** table to list all failed mails.

Is there anyway i can process/re-send these failed mail's?

Would it be reasonable to create a daily job to query this table looping through using a **CURSOR** to re-send the mails one by one, and then delete them from the table one by one.

If you have a better suggestion / ideas then please let me know.

Many thanks Karl

Comment: Do you know why they're failing? You could just resolve that rather than write a new procedure.

Comment: The error im getting is - The mail could not be sent to the recipients because of the mail server failure. (A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.  Whats weird is all other applciations use the same mail host with no issues.

Answer (score 1):

First up, i suggest you query faileditems to determine your main cause of failure:

```
SELECT  items.subject ,
        items.last_mod_date ,
        l.description
FROM    dbo.sysmail_faileditems AS items
        INNER JOIN dbo.sysmail_event_log AS l ON items.mailitem_id = l.mailitem_id
```

If it's nothing that can be easily fixed, you can re-send them by looping through the sysmail_mailitems table and re-sending them based on the failure type (timeouts etc) in the faileditems log - some good examples in the suggestions of this blog: http://justgeeks.blogspot.co.uk/2007/05/resending-sysmail-emails.html

My personal favourite:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sysmail_resend_timeout
AS 
    BEGIN
        SET NOCOUNT ON

        DECLARE SYSMAIL_LOG_RESEND_CURSOR CURSOR READ_ONLY
        FOR
            SELECT DISTINCT
                    l.mailitem_id ,
                    p.name ,
                    m.recipients ,
                    m.subject ,
                    m.body_format ,
                    m.body
            FROM    msdb.dbo.sysmail_log l WITH ( NOLOCK )
                    JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmail_mailitems m WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON m.mailitem_id = l.mailitem_id
                    JOIN msdb.dbo.sysmail_profile p WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON p.profile_id = m.profile_id
            WHERE   l.event_type = 3
                    AND m.sent_status = 2
                    AND l.description LIKE '%The operation has timed out%'
            ORDER BY l.mailitem_id

        OPEN SYSMAIL_LOG_RESEND_CURSOR

        WHILE ( 1 = 1 ) 
            BEGIN
                DECLARE @mailitem_id INT ,
                    @profile_name NVARCHAR(128) ,
                    @recipients VARCHAR(MAX) ,
                    @subject NVARCHAR(255) ,
                    @body_format VARCHAR(20) ,
                    @body NVARCHAR(MAX)
                FETCH NEXT FROM SYSMAIL_LOG_RESEND_CURSOR INTO @mailitem_id, @profile_name, @recipients, @subject, @body_format, @body
                IF NOT @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
                    BEGIN
                        BREAK
                    END

                PRINT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 121) + CHAR(9) + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @mailitem_id) + CHAR(9) + @recipients

                EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail 
                    @profile_name = @profile_name ,
                    @recipients = @recipients ,
                    @subject = @subject ,
                    @body_format = @body_format ,
                    @body = @body

                UPDATE  msdb.dbo.sysmail_mailitems
                SET     sent_status = 3
                WHERE   mailitem_id = @mailitem_id

            END

        CLOSE SYSMAIL_LOG_RESEND_CURSOR

        DEALLOCATE SYSMAIL_LOG_RESEND_CURSOR

    END
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

I know it's not really the answer you want to hear, but I always try and decouple the mail feature.  I might use a trigger to spawn an external process if the mail sending needs to be timely, but I let the external script do the actual job of sending the mail.  That way transient connection errors are taken care of by the MTA, and I don't have to worry about special book-keeping algorithms.